# Is it possible to use dynamic_features in meetme?

Tags: asterisk

I want to add MeetMeAdmin command in the conference channel using DYNAMIC_FEATURES. consider the following configuration.

- features.conf

`[applicationmap]`

`MuteNonAdmin = #23,self,MeetMeAdmin(${CONF_NO},N)`

- extensions.conf

`exten => 112,1,Answer()`

`same => n,Set(CONF_NO=112)`

`same => n,Set(__DYNAMIC_FEATURES=MuteNonAdmin)`

`same => n,MeetMe(${CONF_NO},as)`

so when user logged in to the conference as admin should be able to use "#23" feature code to mute all non admin user, but this does not work. i'm not even sure if DYNAMIC_FEATURE works properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is posible.

But usually not needed, becuase meetme allow do customized menu. Since you are not expert, check confbridge menu, it simpler to setup.

Note, it can be limits for commands used via features, but you always can throw user-event, catch it by external program and do whatever you want.

For debug i recommend you check that CONF_NO variable is set in applicatio(for example via Verbose command).

Comment: I'm using Asterisk 1.8 which doesn't have these new features and i think confbridge menu is available in Asterisk 10.

Comment: Yes, before * 10.X menu can be done via context/same for meetme.